# Print the Sequence of Minimum number of Jumps required to reach the end of an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am  given an array of integers with values greater than or equal to 0, for example:
[5, 6, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4]

I am asked to implement an algorithm to traverse the array in the shortest number of “hops” starting at index 0, where traversal is defined as follows:

->Start at the first (0th) index of the array, look at the array value there, and you can hop forward to any array index that is no farther than that value away. So in this example, you start at index 0 containing the value 5 and can now consider hopping to any of indices 1 through 5 inclusive.

If I choose to hop to index 3, it contains the value 4 and I can next hop up to 4 more spots from my current index (3)—so I now consider indices 4 through 7 as next steps in the sequence.

My algorithm must identify a minimum-hops solution, but can choose arbitrarily among solutions with the same number of hops.

For this example, the following would be valid output:

0, 5, 9, out

This is my Implementation:

```
public class ArrayJumper {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    int[] minJumps(int arr[], int n) {
        int jumps[] = new int[n];
        int tab[] = new int[n];// jumps[n-1] will hold the result
        int i, j;
        jumps[0] = 0;
        tab[0] = 0;

        if (n == 0 || arr[0] == 0) {
            return jumps;
        }

        // Find the minimum number of jumps to reach arr[i]
        // from arr[0], and assign this value to jumps[i]

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            jumps[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (i <= j + arr[j] && jumps[j] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    if (jumps[i] >= jumps[j] + 1) {
                        jumps[i] = jumps[j] + 1;
                        tab[i] = j;
                        //break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jumps));

        return tab;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int arr[] = {5, 6, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4};
        //int arr[] = {2,3,1,1,2,4,2,0,1,1};
        int n = arr.length;
        int res[] = new int[n];
        int inn[] = new int[n];
        ArrayJumper a = new ArrayJumper();
        inn = a.minJumps(arr, n);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inn));

        inn[0] = 0;
        String ans = " 0 ,";

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (inn[i] != inn[i + 1]) {
                ans = ans.concat(inn[i + 1] + ",");
            }
        }
        if (arr[inn[n - 1]] + inn[n - 1] == n - 1) {
            ans = ans.concat(n - 1 + ",");
        }

        ans = ans.concat("out");
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

However the solution works for given input, It fails for the following output:
{2,3,1,1,2,4,2,0,1,1};
I am not sure where I am missing out. Both the commented input works correctly If I change the break statement respectively. 
So how do I modify this progroam to get

0,1,4,5,9,out for the input {2,3,1,1,2,4,2,0,1,1}.

and 
0, 5, 9, out for the input {5, 6, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4}

Comment: Seems to me like a greedy algorithm won't work here, in fact is smells quite a lot like the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), specifically the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Subset-sum_problem). This is NP-complete.

Comment: And just for the record: this is not a "we debug your code for you" service. If your code isn't doing what you expect it to do, learn how to use a debugger so that **you** yourself can gain more insight into what is happening. Or at least: add trace statements in order to be able to "observe" your code while it is doing its work. And I agree with Boris; probably you simply picked an approach that will not work here.

Comment: What I see from some solution online is that..  these are classic DP problems.  I found some videos in YouTube too.  I implemented this with the help of it

Comment: @GhostCat.  Thanks.  I Tried this for continuous 12 hours and asked in community when I was not able to find the reason for the error. Sure I will add comments too.

Comment: And what did you tried during those 12hours ? I see a requirement, a code (with only a few comments) and some inputs but not much. Did you have any leads on the problem ?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @slim, that’s a wonderful collection of tips. I believe many of them are not particularly well suited for this particular case — the rubber duck thing should be good, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `minJumps()` is working correctly. Your problem is with the construction of the answer, the `ans` string.

I didn’t understand the logic in the way you are trying to do it. I believe you need to build the string backward from “out”. When `inn[3]` equals 2, it means that *if* your solution goes through index 3 of the input, it should go through index 2 before 3. But you don’t know yet whether the solution will jump through index 3.

So to build it backward, you start from “out”, and what comes before “out”? To tell, you need to have the result array one element longer so the new last element tells you the last index to visit before “out”. Then you can do:

```
    String ans = "out";
    int index = n;
    while (index > 0) {
        index = inn[index];
        ans = "" + index + ", " + ans;
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
```

To build the array one element longer requires just some simple changes to your method:

```
    int jumps[] = new int[n + 1];
    int tab[] = new int[n + 1];// jumps[n-1] will hold the result
```

and

```
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

With these changes, input {5, 6, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4} yields

```
0, 5, 9, out
```

Input {2,3,1,1,2,4,2,0,1,1} gives

```
0, 1, 4, 5, 9, out
```